# Performance tuning in update statement with DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle12c, query-performance

I have below update statement which include a reference to a table and a DECODE statement. My table has around 500000 records which will alter by this statement and it is taking around 2 1/2 hours to finish. Any types of suggestions are welcome to enhance the performance of this.

**Here comes my update statement**

```
   UPDATE TABlE_1 t1
  SET t1.column_1= DECODE( (SELECT creator 
                            FROM table_2 t2
                            WHERE t2.key1 = t1.key1 
                            AND   t2.key2 = t1.key2), 
                            'AAAAAAA_table2', 
                            'aaaaa_table1', 
                            'BBBBBBB_table2', 
                            'bbbbb_table1', 
                            'ccccc_table1')
  WHERE t1.column_1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Why is performance important? This looks like a one-time update, or are you going to update all 500000 records often?

Comment: This is a part of a update script which used to upgrade customer databases and the upgrade process should be rather quick. yes this is a one time upgrade

Answer (score 0):

If the number of options in the decode statement is not too large, you may be better off running a number of targeted update statements.

e.g.

```
    UPDATE table_1 t1 
    SET t1.column_1 = 'aaaaa_table_1' 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM table_2 t2
                 WHERE t2.key1 = t1.key1 
                 AND   t2.key2 = t1.key2
                 AND creator = 'AAAAAA') 
   AND t1.column_1 IS NULL
```

And then repeat this for each mapping you are trying to perform.

Comment: Oracle does not allow a `from` clause in an `update` statement.

Comment: Here is a brief discussion of the correct syntax for updating through a join in Oracle. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201704042229465657268

Comment: @Tom Kimber 's suggestion was helpful for me even though the syntax is not correct. I had only 5 options in my DECODE statement and when I divide them in to 5 different statement and visit the table 5 times. The execution time was reduced by 1hour.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a rule that transforms the CREATOR value when inserting to TABLE_1.
How about just applying the rule.

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
   SET t1.column_1 = (SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(creator,1,5))||'_table1' 
                        FROM table_2 t2
                       WHERE t2.key1 = t1.key1 
                         AND t2.key2 = t1.key2)
  WHERE t1.column_1 IS NULL
```

Or use a merge statement

```
MERGE INTO table_1 t1
USING (SELECT LOWER(SUBSTR(creator,1,5))||'_table1' AS derived_creator
         FROM table_2) t2  
       ON (    t2.key1 = t1.key1 
           AND t2.key2 = t1.key2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.column_1 = t2.derived_creator
```

I haven't run these on a dataset so can't say that either would be quicker. However, I think that they both look neater. 
As an aside it is recommended that the CASE expression be used in SQL now instead of the DECODE function which would give you the SQL below.

```
UPDATE TABlE_1 t1
   SET t1.column_1= SELECT CASE creator 
                           WHEN 'AAAAAAA_table2' THEN 'aaaaa_table1'
                           WHEN 'BBBBBBB_table2' THEN 'bbbbb_table1'
                           ELSE 'ccccc_table1'
                           END                           
                      FROM table_2 t2
                     WHERE t2.key1 = t1.key1 
                       AND t2.key2 = t1.key2
  WHERE t1.column_1 IS NULL
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a "rule" at all; if the `creator` is `'abc'` then the value used for update needs to be `'ccccc_table1'`. Also, the `CASE` thing is a `CASE expression` (rather than "condition").

Comment: @mathguy - the example in the OP shows two 'transforms' where the first part is made lower-case and shortened and a fall through transform using 'ccccc'. I see no mention of 'abc'. That looks like a rule to me.

Comment: The "fall through" applies to any value OTHER THAN the ones specifically included otherwise (AAAAAA_table2 and BBBBBB_table2). Any other value, such as abc, is replaced with ccccc_table2 as the result of the DECODE function.

Comment: In here I cant derive the value from the column "Creator" even though I set it like "AAAAA" and aaaa_Table1 for clarity

Comment: @Dimuthu - fair enough. Based on the example i misunderstood your intent. I'll delete the answer shortly as it doesn't help you at all.

Comment: @BriteSponge No I dont think you should delete the answer. Please keep it since using the MERGE operation in update is quite helpful even this example cant get anything about it I guess. Also your statement about switch case